# Skip line if string is empty

Tags: c#

I want to skip a line, if a string is empty.

I try it like this:

```
public void ReadPostedData()
{
    Sender = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_sender"];
    Subject = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_subject"];        
    Message = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Message"];
    PdfMessage = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["PdfMessage"];

    string IsCheckPDfMailSubmit = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["IsCheckedPDFMailForm"];
    if (IsCheckPDfMailSubmit == null || IsCheckPDfMailSubmit.Length == 0)

        //string.IsNullOrEmpty(IsCheckPDfMailSubmit);

    return IsCheckPDfMailSubmit == null;

    IsCheckedPDFMailForm = IsCheckPDfMailSubmit.Equals("True", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 

    string v = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_includeoverviewpdf"];
    IncludeOverviewPdf = v.Equals("true,false", StringComparison.Ordinal) ? true : false;
    // http://forums.asp.net/t/1314753.aspx

    ApplicantMailNodeSelectors[0] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_applicantemailaddress1"];
    ApplicantMailNodeSelectors[1] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_applicantemailaddress2"];
    ApplicantMailNodeSelectors[2] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_applicantemailaddress3"];
}
```

it is about this line:

```
if (IsCheckPDfMailSubmit == null || IsCheckPDfMailSubmit.Length == 0)
```

if it is null, dont execute this line:

```
IsCheckedPDFMailForm = IsCheckPDfMailSubmit.Equals("True", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

I try it like this:

```
return IsCheckPDfMailSubmit == null;
```

But then I get the following error:

> Error  6   Since 'Seneca.SfsLib.Connectors.MailFormSubmitterModel.ReadPostedData()' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression

So how to skip that?

Comment: `dont execute this line` - that line *only*? Or you mean return from the method entirely?

Comment: You function has a void return type therefore it doesn't expect you to return anything. if you want to skip code following the check, wrap the whole block in the conditional and only execute it when the satisfying condition exists.

Comment: Have you tried this: string.IsNullOrEmpty(IsCheckPDfMailSubmit )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to exit from the function depending on the condition in the `if` statement, you use just `return;` when the method has `void` as return type:

```
if (IsCheckPDfMailSubmit == null || IsCheckPDfMailSubmit.Length == 0) {
  return;
}
```

Alternatively, instead of exiting in the midde of the function, you can reverse the condition and put the rest of the code inside the `if` statement:

```
if (!(IsCheckPDfMailSubmit == null || IsCheckPDfMailSubmit.Length == 0)) {
  // ...
  // rest of the code in the method
  // ...
}
```

If you just want to skip the following line but resume with the rest of the code in the method, reverse the condition and put that line in the `if` statement:

```
if (!(IsCheckPDfMailSubmit == null || IsCheckPDfMailSubmit.Length == 0)) {
  IsCheckedPDFMailForm = IsCheckPDfMailSubmit.Equals("True", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! Is doing the job

Answer (score 0):

Your method is void type as such you cannot return any value. Expression `return IsCheckPDfMailSubmit == null;` attempts to return a bool is not correct, as such you get a compiler error.

You can fix it couple of ways, one way could be to change your if condition to check for alternate case.

```
public void ReadPostedData()
{
    Sender = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_sender"];
    Subject = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_subject"];        
    Message = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Message"];
    PdfMessage = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["PdfMessage"];

    string IsCheckPDfMailSubmit = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["IsCheckedPDFMailForm"];
    if (IsCheckPDfMailSubmit != null && IsCheckPDfMailSubmit.Length > 0)
    // A better option is to use string.IsNullOrEmpty:
    // if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IsCheckPDfMailSubmit))
    {

    IsCheckedPDFMailForm = IsCheckPDfMailSubmit.Equals("True", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 





    string v = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_includeoverviewpdf"];
    IncludeOverviewPdf = v.Equals("true,false", StringComparison.Ordinal) ? true : false;
    // http://forums.asp.net/t/1314753.aspx

    ApplicantMailNodeSelectors[0] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_applicantemailaddress1"];
    ApplicantMailNodeSelectors[1] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_applicantemailaddress2"];
    ApplicantMailNodeSelectors[2] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_applicantemailaddress3"];
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public void ReadPostedData()
{
    Sender = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_sender"];
    Subject = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_subject"];        
    Message = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Message"];
    PdfMessage = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["PdfMessage"];

    string IsCheckPDfMailSubmit = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["IsCheckedPDFMailForm"];
    if (IsCheckPDfMailSubmit != null) {
        if(IsCheckPDfMailSubmit.Length > 0){
            IsCheckedPDFMailForm = IsCheckPDfMailSubmit.Equals("True", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
        }
    }





    string v = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_includeoverviewpdf"];
    IncludeOverviewPdf = v.Equals("true,false", StringComparison.Ordinal) ? true : false;
// http://forums.asp.net/t/1314753.aspx

    ApplicantMailNodeSelectors[0] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_applicantemailaddress1"];
    ApplicantMailNodeSelectors[1] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_applicantemailaddress2"];
    ApplicantMailNodeSelectors[2] = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["MailFormSubmitter_applicantemailaddress3"];
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this got down voted considering I answered with exactly what you asked.